# Trying to generate html in a Blazor project

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I am trying to make multiple boxes.  I have an error saying cannot convert from void to object.  This is my first time with Blazor.  Where have I gone wrong?

My select list-

```
<form method="post" action="">
      
       Groups<br />
       <select @bind="groups">
        @for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
       </select>
</form>

       <p>Selected Value: @groups</p>
```

Running the method

```
     <div>
         @makeGroups()
     </div>

    @code{

       int groups = 1;

       void makeGroups()
       {
          for (int i = 1; i <= groups; i++)
          {
        
            <div class="leftBox">

            </div>

            <div class="middleBox">

            </div>

            <div class="rightBox">

            </div>
      }
    }
```

Comment: You.can Not add HTML inside the @Code block, why do you need that method?

Comment: I am attempting to create an amount of divs  chosen by the app user.  Do I need to add the html with the loop inside a div that is withing the body? I am trying to run the method from within the body.

Comment: You may add a for or a foreach loop in the HTML part of your racer component but not HTML in the code part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple ways to achieve what you want. I will list a few options/ideas.

1. First option is to have the for loop inside the html part:

```
<form method="post" action="">
        
    Groups<br />
    <select @bind="groups">
        @for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
</form>

<p>Selected Value: @groups</p>

<div>
    @for (int i = 1; i <= groups; i++)
    {
        <div class="leftBox">    
        
        </div>

        <div class="middleBox">

        </div>

        <div class="rightBox">

        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    int groups = 1;
}
```

2. You can add the for loop in a separate blazor component.

e.g.: `GroupsComponent.razor`:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfGroups; i++)
{
    <div class="leftBox">

    </div>

    <div class="middleBox">

    </div>

    <div class="rightBox">

    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] 
    public int NumberOfGroups { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">

    Groups<br />
    <select @bind="groups">
        @for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
</form>

<p>Selected Value: @groups</p>

<div>
    <GroupsComponent NumberOfGroups="groups" />
</div>

@code {

    int groups = 1;
}
```

3. you can create a method that returns `RenderFragment` similar to your initial code. (not recommended, results in not clean code):

```
<form method="post" action="">

    Groups<br />
    <select @bind="groups">
        @for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
</form>

<p>Selected Value: @groups</p>

<div>
    @MakeGroups()
</div>

@code {
    
    int groups = 1;

    private RenderFragment MakeGroups()
    {
        return (__builder) =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= groups; i++)
            {
                <div class="leftBox">

                </div>
    
                <div class="middleBox">

                </div>
    
                <div class="rightBox">

                </div>
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. This is a lot to absorb.   I tried the render fragment with no luck.  I will give your first suggestion a go first. It looks like the easiest.

Comment: Thank Dimitris.  i was trying to add html with a method.  Your suggestion had no method.  Just let the for loop run!  Its simple and elegant.